# Write to file (Nagios3)

Tags: nagios, command, write

I try to make script/command in nagios3 at write in new file some data but nagios will not do that. I try that simple bash command:

> printf "something" > /path-to-file/new-file

But nagios don't open/write file. I try direct i definition of nagios commando and to make bash script and start from nagios but same - nothing happens.

Look like:

`define command{ 
command_name    service-notify-sms 
command_line    /usr/bin/printf '%s\n\n%s\n%s\n%s' "To: $CONTACTPAGER$ " "Service : $SERVICEDESC$ " "State: $SERVICESTATE$ " "Date/Time: $LONGDATETIME$ " > /var/spool/sms/outgoing/$CONTACTPAGER$ 
}`

`define contact{
    service_notification_commands  service-notify-sms
    host_notification_commands     host-notify-sms`

I think about at nagios need some privilege to write file or I think wrong?
Maybe nagios can't write file or have some another command, not standard bash ">"?

It's look in /var/log/syslog:

`Jun 13 08:58:00 nagios nagios3: HOST NOTIFICATION: user-sms;Nagios;CUSTOM (UP);host-notify-sms;OK - localhost responds to ICMP. Packet 1, rtt 0.010ms;nagiosadmin;test`

I founded about only one question: Is this possible at Nagios write in file or not? It someone do some like that?

Comment: Showing the nagios configuration might help with the debugging.

Comment: define command{
    command_name    service-notify-sms
    command_line    /usr/bin/printf '%s\n\n%s\n%s\n%s' "To: $CONTACTPAGER$ " "Service : $SERVICEDESC$ " "State: $SERVICESTATE$ " "Date/Time: $LONGDATETIME$ " > /var/spool/sms/outgoing/$CONTACTPAGER$
    }

Comment: Where else in the nagios configuration is `service-notify-sms` used?

Comment: define contact{

    service_notification_commands  service-notify-sms

    host_notification_commands     host-notify-sms

Comment: Permissions to the spool directory?

Comment: @lazyfrosch this is so unusually because I think direct permission but it's not, because I try all: change owner, permissions on spool dir and file/script ...

Comment: do you see "service-notify-sms" in the Nagios log? Ideally, in a line that starts with SERVICE NOTIFICATION

Comment: @Keith yes, and everything stay it's OK

Comment: I don't know ... I just want to know are somebody do some command to write in file on the end from nagios? and if everything was ok?

Comment: sudo -H -u nagios bash -c '/usr/bin/printf > /var/spool/sms/outgoing/$CONTACTPAGER$'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was at must nagios user be in group smsd ...